# Batch Ftp: How do I set the local download directory dynamically?

Tags: batch-file, ftp, dir

What i'm trying to do is this.
1) Create a Directory with the date as its name.
2)Download Contents of a Folder on a server into the directory that's just been made.

This is what i've done so far:

execute.bat:

```
 @echo off
 for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a
mkdir %datestr%

ftp -i -s:link.bat
```

link.bat

```
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a
  ftp 
  IP_ADDRESS_HERE
  USERNAME
  PASSWORD
  lcd "C:\SOME_DIR\%datestr%"
  mget *
  diconnect 
  quit
```

I just cant get this to work, the LCD is actually looking for %datestr% in my file system. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of 'date /t' bla bla you could use %date%

Answer (score 0):

This single batch file creates the script and then uses it with FTP.  Make sure that the `datestr` format is right for your location and regional settings.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set "datestr=%%a"
mkdir "%datestr%" 2>nul

(
  echo open IP_ADDRESS_HERE
  echo USERNAME
  echo PASSWORD
  echo lcd "C:\SOME_DIR\%datestr%"
  echo mget *
  echo diconnect 
  echo quit
)>link.txt

ftp -i -s:link.txt
del link.txt
```